# Using checkboxes created with map method in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

Hope you can help me here.

Lets say i have a list of items created using map method in react js.

Each list of items contains text and checkbox (checkbox from materual ui lib).

Now i have a problem with using checkboxes, as when i add controls to them (checked and onChange()) props - whenever i tick 1 box - all boxes are ticked. And vice versa.
However, the idea is that once I check 1 checkbox - it should cross out the text next to the that box (some kind todo list).

Please, give me some hits how can i do that? How to be able each checkbox.

```
 <div className="lidiv">
    {items.map((item: any, index: number) => (
      <li
        key={item.id}
        style={{
          background: index % 2 === 0 ? "lightgray" : "transparent",
          padding: 3,
          textDecoration: decor,
        }}
      >
        {index + 1}
        <Box> {item.description}</Box>
        <Box>
          <Checkbox
            checked={checked}
            onChange={(e) => handleTick(item.id, e)}
          />
          <DeleteIcon
            sx={{ color: red[500], mb: -1 }}
            onClick={() => deleteItem(item.id)}
          />
        </Box>
      </li>
    ))}
  </div>
```

Comment: Where did you define `checked` variable?

Comment: const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
const handleTick = (id: any) => {
    checked ? setChecked(false) : setChecked(true);
  };

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the important part of the code and from your comment it seems that you were handling every items in one state, you need to have state for each item.

```js
const { useState } = React

const App = () => {
  
  const [items, setItems] = useState([{
    name: 'test 1',
    checked: false
  }, {
    name: 'test 2',
    checked: false
  }, {
    name: 'test 3',
    checked: false
  }]);
  

  const handleCheckBox = (event, index) => {
      const checked = event.target.checked;
      setItems(items => {

        return [

          ...items.slice(0, index),

          {...items[index], checked},

          ...items.slice(index + 1),
        ]
      })
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      {
        items.map((item, i) => 
          <div key={i}>
              <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => handleCheckBox(e, i)}/>
              <span style={{ textDecoration: item.checked? 'line-through': 'none' }}>{item.name}</span>
          </div>
        )
      }
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply! much appreciated. i didnt post the important part as i wasnt sure what to post. I guess that was my question - how to handle state for each checkbox. I will try  ur code and let you know if it worked for me.